# Cognito Users Migrated between pools - confirmed - but mobile not verified - " User is already confirmed" error on resendConfirmationCode

Tags: amazon-cognito

We are migrating users from a pool where we stored (but did not verify) users `email`s and `phone_number`s, to a pool where we want to validate their mobile phone numbers, as we will be sending them text messages.

Once migrated, the user is marked as 'confirmed' (necessary for them to log in), and we bring the `phone_number` and `email` attributes into the new user in the new pool. However, we have never validated their mobile phone numbers using a SMS confirmation code.

If I update the users `phone_number`, cognito automatically resends a code and their updated number which I can then confirm.

My problem is for people who's migrated number is correct, but I just want them to verify it. I have a screen for them to check the number, and if it is correct, I call

`cognitoUser.resendConfirmationCode()`

Cognito does not send the code, and responds with:

`InvalidParameterException: User is already confirmed.`

One solution I can think of is to change the cognito number twice - once to some incorrect number, and a second time to their real number. This will send two messages, but will achieve what I want.

Is there a better way to mark a confirmed user's existing phone number as verified using the SMS?